# Page layout not editable in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout

When I try to edit the page in SharePoint Designer it assk to checkout and edit the page layout, but I am not able edit the page in designer.

I want to edit **List view web part** code in page, but it not possible to edit page `default.aspx`

Answer (score 1):

You're using a publishing page. A publishing page is made of a publishing layout and a master page.

The master page is responsible for displaying all the "chrome" (navigation, menus...) and the layout for the body area structure (user-authored publishing content).

In SharePoint Designer, you can edit both the master page or the layout. But everything else (including Web parts) is content added/edited by users Inside the placeholders of the content areas of the layout!

So, to edit Web parts on a publishing page, the only option is to switch the page to edit mode from the browser, and edit the Web part properties.

If you need super-tuning of a Web part, you can also super-tune it on a standard (non-publishing page) from SPD, export it as an WML file, and import it into the publishing page while in edit mode (from the Insert Web part panel).